# Durable messaging over HTTP

Tags: architecture, microservices, azure, messaging, service-bus

I need to send messages from a Windows Service to a Azure Service Fabric Stateful service. The network connection is not very reliable, and there must not be lost data. I was hoping I could use NServiceBus with a store & forward pattern to send the messages. Is my thinking fundamentally flawed?

Comment: I don't know NServiceBus specifically - is it some kind of message queue?

Comment: Yeah its an abstraction for messaging on top of a transport of your choice, MSMQ, RabbitMQ, Azure Service Bus, etc.

Comment: As I understand it, NServiceBus transactions make certain guarantees about the delivery of your data (the durability of those guarantees is configuration-settable).  Does that answer your question?  More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3515372

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to guarantee that no data is ever lost. There are ways to *diminish* the chance, and there are ways to *detect* when the data is lost -- and this is the best you can do.

Given this premise, a TCP connection is actually pretty good in this regard, as it *guarantees* delivery of a message or a failure.

The question then boils down to: what do you do if there is a failure? Here are some options:

1. Throw an error and stop the application
2. Log the error to a file or a printer, including the data
3. Store the data somewhere, like a database, and resend automatically
4. Store the data in a distributed queue with guaranteed delivery (note: queues normally depend on some form of database to guarantee durability!)
5. Use redundant Windows services with the same data with different connections and deduplicate on the other side.

All of these solutions fit with the requirement of "no lost data" once you understand that handling failures is the best we can do. In fact you can even use all of them at the same time (falling back if anyone fails). Of course they have wildly different costs. Which one is appropriate depends on how much the lost data is valuable to you and how much you are prepared to spend.

Comment: I should have said minimal data loss, I certainly understand that nothing is 100% fail proof. NServiceBus provides enough guarantees for our data, I'm mainly just wondering how I make a call from a Windows service over the wire to an Azure Service Fabric Service.

Comment: Is 'Log the error to a file or a printer' a quote from some 80s book? ;)

Comment: @IlliakaillI not really, logging errors is quite common even today.

Comment: @Sklivvz logging to a printer, really? Oh, I see, it must be that situation when ATM is printing 'transaction failed' on my receipt.

Comment: @IlliakaillI or more generally logging to a serial port or a printer is quite common in many other embedded scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think nservicebus has the support right now for what you are looking for.  Using the azure servicebus broker would be just as unreliable as your network connection, so that is no solution.

What you would need is a locally stored outbox (not to be confused with nsb's current outbox feature) + some kind of failure proof pump that pushes the messages over once network is reestablished. This is on my wishlist for quite some time, https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.AzureServiceBus/issues/22, but not implemented yet due to lack of local storage capabilities in most azure services.

For this scenario however it could be built using msmq as local store (assuming it's on a non transient disk) & service fabric reliable state management as remote store on the service fabric side. But on other services, e.g. cloudservices it would be dangerous as the disks gets reimaged every now and then.

Comment: Doesn't Azure Service Bus have the ability to communicate with on premise servers? Does NServiceBus not support this?

Comment: Sure it does, but you state that the network is extremely unreliable. To reach ASB you need network connectivity

Answer (score 0):

1) Set up an NServiceBus endpoint with MSMQ on the box with the Windows Server. It will use the built-in store and forward capabilities of MSMQ not to lose messages locally on that machine.

2) Set up one or more NServiceBus endpoints in Azure Service Fabric. There you would probably use ASB as transport for service to service communication.

3) Use the NServiceBus gateway to bridge between 1) and 2) through a HTTP(s) channel. It will do automatic retries if the connection is down and it does de-duplication to give you exactly-once message delivery through HTTP(s). Is was specifically built for these multi-site scenarios.

Comment: I like this approach, it seems very clean. How does this approach differ in reliability to a connection using Azure Service Bus's hybrid relay solutions?

Comment: Also, our issue with this approach is our (1) doesn't have a fixed public address.

Comment: I must admit limited knowledge about the relay functionality in ASB, but my impression is that it is there to help integrate on-premise with Azure through HTTPS/WebSocket tunnelling. It is still RPC based though, so it will suffer from the same connection unreliability problems that caused you to not just use ASB everywhere in the first place. No store-and-forward, no retries and no de-duplication.

Comment: If you don't have to initiate any send from 2) to 1), that should not be a problem.

Comment: You do need a public address on 2) though. Not sure how/if that is possible ATM with SF Stateful Service. I recommend trying to create a small end-to- end proof of concept to try it out.

Comment: Service Fabric now has a reverse proxy https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy that could be used to expose the gateway over a public address,